# Javascript button handler

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="myFunc()"> Execute function </a>
```

In Chrome inspector the error I get is:

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Below is how my code looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    
   
    <body>
         

      <div id="root"></div>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
      <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="myFunc()"> Execute function </a>
      <script>  
        
       
        function myFunc() { 
            // some code here
    }    
      </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="myFunc()"> Execute function </a>

<script>
function myFunc() { 
    // some code here
}    
</script>
```

Put the anchor tag out of script tag, you are putting tags inside javascript so that is why error is result.

Comment: put your script inside head and tags inside body.. thats good practice